# C:Way to remove multiple values from a loop in a function

Tags: c, function, return, return-value

I need to create a file ie : `Earth.txt`, then put in multiple `x` and `y` coordinates from a loop, then close the file before opening a new file ie: `Mars.txt` with new boundary conditions and repeating (ideally without putting the creation of the file in the loop, else id have to change the name manually each time to stop it overriding the previous data).

I can't find a way to return the values into my main body of code and put them in the file. If I use `return x` or `return y` it gives me the last value whether inside or outside of the loop.

```
int main (){
    //Earth

    float ex = -147095000000, ey = 0, evx0 = 0, evy0 = -30300.0;

    FILE*outfile;
    outfile=fopen("Earth.txt", "w");
    Integration(ex, ey, evx0, evy0);
    fprintf(outfile,"This is x:%f\n",x);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

And this is the function I need to extract my `x` values from:

```
float Integration(int *x, int *y, float vx0, float vy0){

    double k_1_x, k_2_x, k_1_y, k_2_y, k_1_vx ,k_1_vy, k_2_vx, k_2_vy;
    double dt = 86400; //seconds per day

    int i;

    for (i=0;i<800;i++){
        k_1_x = vx0;
        k_1_y = vy0;

        printf("x1:%f\ny1:%f\nvx1:%f\nvy1%f\n", *x, *y, vx0, vy0);

        return X;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I should basically end up with 800 different `x` values printed into my file.

Comment: `return X;` inside the loop doesn't make sense (the return value of that function is ignored anyway). I think you should use an `fprintf(outfile, ...);` instead of the `printf` there, to fill the file.

Comment: if i use fprintf(outfile....) there is dosnt recognise i've opened the file as its opened during the main and not the function.

Comment: Pass the file pointer into Integration.  Do the writing there and you don't need to return unless there is an error.

Comment: files stay open until closed - regardless of what function you are in.

Comment: thank you, could i have an explanation on how to do this or a link explaining. Am very new to coding.

Comment: Make a new parameter for `Integration(FILE *outfile, ...)` and then use fprintf() in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
for (i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    // ...
    return X;  // <- Unconditioned
}
```

Is not a loop. The body will be executed only once and a single value (whatever `X` is) is returned (and ignored by the rest of the posted code, BTW).

If I have understood the task you are trying to accomplish, you might change the function into something like this

```
void Integration(FILE *out, double x0, double y0, double vx0, double vy0)
{
    double k_1_x, k_2_x, k_1_y, k_2_y, k_1_vx ,k_1_vy, k_2_vx, k_2_vy;
    double x = x0, y = y0, vx = vx0, vy = vy0;
    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 800; ++i)
    {
        // Update the variables x, y, vx, vy...
        fprintf(out, "%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", x, y, vx, vy);
        //             ^^ Use the correct format specifier for doubles
    }
}
```

Also you should change the `main` into

```
int main(void)
{
    //Earth
    double ex = -147095000000, ey = 0, evx0 = 0, evy0 = -30300.0;

    FILE *outfile = fopen("Earth.txt", "w");
    if (!outfile)
        // Deal with the error

    Integration(outfile, ex, ey, evx0, evy0);
    fclose(outfile);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: beware fprintf() is trying to print floats to the file instead of doubles...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks, good catch (I just copy-pasted that part...).

Comment: doing so tells me i get an error : Incompatible type for argument 2 of integration

Comment: @Eleanor Yes, there were some mismatches in the used types. You used both `int` and `float` in the function signature, but unless there are specific requirements, I'd suggest to use  `double` for all the variables in your calculations (except for the indices, of course). May I ask why you were using pointers to `int` for `x` and `y` while in main you passed two `float` values?

Comment: Upon changing the ones i can see it still passes them same error.  Is there a particular one i should be looking to change?

Comment: @Eleanor Well, it would help to see the real code and the exact error message. My dummy implementation "works", [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/az9pX1RwbuQQb8DJ).

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/oUyNg3qgBRdXCYfz Here is the relevent parts of my code. Many thanks. It is now creating a file and printing the values in the terminal but not printing the values into the file created

Comment: @Eleanor Ok, so there are no errors, there. Does it work, on your computer (using `outfile` instead of `stdout`, of course)?

Comment: oh gosh you star! That's worked perfectly, youve helped me so much, Thank you.

Comment: @Eleanor If I may, I'd also suggest to use a single function to calculate the acceleration, just passing `x` *or* `y`. I usually avoid `pow(x, 2)` too, a simple `x * x` would be enough.

Comment: Ill give thought on it. May i also ask one more question. if i go to do this with more planets as planned, i have to open another new text file.  The issue is it says im redefining it https://wandbox.org/permlink/PhUf2XzAm59wlK0V

Comment: @Eleanor Note the text of the error, the compiler is complaining about the *redefinition* of the variable. You could just *reassign* it with `outfile = fopen(...)` (note the lack of the type) or define *another* variable: `FILE *mars_out = fopen(...)`.

Comment: That's fixed that to and i've implemented it into my greater code. All working now. Thank you for your help!